# Grep file modified in 24 hours unix

Tags: unix

I have to check the user and owner of that file which is modified in last 24 hours .I am not able to understand how could i get the file which is modified in last 24 hour

```
ls -lrt /dirpath | grep 'Util'
```

Output of this command is :

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user user      186 Apr 11 08:05 Util-04-11.log.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user user      185 Apr 12 08:05 Util-04-12.log.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user user      186 Apr 13 08:05 Util-04-13.log.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user user      186 Apr 14 08:05 Util-04-14.log.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 user user      278 Apr 20 08:05 Util-04-20.log
```

Now i want to check user and owner of file which is modified in last 24 hours.How we can do this in unix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` to filter files with corresponding modified date.

From the man page:

```
find $HOME -mtime 0
```

> Search  for files in your home directory which have been modified in
>   the last twenty-four hours.  This command works this way because the 
>   time since each file was last modified is divided by 24 hours and
>   any remainder is discarded. That means that to match -mtime 0, a 
>   file will have  to have  a modification in the past which is less 
>   than 24 hours ago.

With that in mind you can use the `-exec` option to build the following command

```
find /dirpath -mtime 0 -exec stat -c "%n %U %G" '{}' \;
```

Comment: i have to find that particular file modifed in last 24 hours then have to check usr and group

Comment: What particular file? Do other files exist? Or use the answer from @j-chomel

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `find` command specifying creation time is less than one day (`-ctime 0`), then use `xargs` to perform your `ls`:

```
find /dirpath -name "*Util*" -ctime 0 -type f |xargs ls -lrt
```

Hope it helps.